# getting values from select with case/if statement depending on condition

Tags: mysql

I am stuck last 2 hours trying to figure out how to make this query or to find an example, till now no result in searching, so I will post here what is my problem. I have a group of users and there is a specific order in which I need to get values.

So group 1 is administrator and he can see all groups, for him the query to get values would be

```
SELECT g1.group_id,g1.description FROM groups g1 ORDER BY g1.description
```

Other groups can see all groups except Administrator group (id in this case is 1), for other users the query to get the values would be:

```
SELECT g2.group_id,g2.description FROM groups g2 WHERE g2.group_id > 1 ORDER BY g2.description
```

I tried to make something with CASE statement but this is not working and I know that subquery cant return more than 1 row, i get an error like this

```
[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

My query is till now, the wrong one:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (SELECT ug.group_id FROM users_groups ug 
        WHERE ug.login="admin" and ug.group_id = 1)
    THEN (SELECT g1.group_id,g1.description FROM groups g1 ORDER BY g1.description)
    ELSE (SELECT g2.group_id,g2.description FROM groups g2 WHERE g2.group_id > 1 ORDER BY g2.description)
END
```

So I need results depending on the group of logged user, if user is admin and his group=1 than he can see all groups, in other way all groups except group 1, admin

any help would be appreciated, the most important thing is that I get the values in this order and only these two g1.group_id,g1.description or g2.group_id,g2.description

Desired output would be :

For user Administrator-

```
group_id description
1        Administrator
2        Customer
3        Supplier
```

For users that are not Administrator-

```
group_id description
2        Customer
3        Supplier
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.description
FROM groups AS g
CROSS JOIN user_groups AS ug
WHERE ug.login = @username
AND (ug.group_id = 1 OR g.group_id > 1)
ORDER BY g.description
```

`@username` is a placeholder for the username performing the query.

Comment: great, you helped me a lot, now i will read a bit about cross join :)

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is just a full cross-product, it has no join condition between the tables. But `WHERE ug.login = @username` restricts it to just one row in the table.